# Only return objects that meet time requirement AWS S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The following code returns all the objects in my S3 bucket:

```
$iterator = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket
));
```

Is it possible to only return files that have been modified(or uploaded) since "X" time? Right now it returns all the files and I have to go through each one and check if it has been modified since "X" time, this adds a significant amount of time and is a more costly approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no built-in mechanism** for that. However, depending on the nature of your requirements you could also consider:

1. Using [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to get the list of the objects prepared by AWS for you in `csv` format. And use that list to get the last objects. It is not real time, as the inventory is created once a day or week.
2. Store metadata of your objects in, e.g., **DynamoDB**. Any new object in your bucket will have its metadata (such as creation time) stored in the DynamoDB. This will allow you efficiently obtain and query the objects that you want to use later on.

There could be other possibilities, such as using two buckets with combination of `replication` and `lifecycles`, to have one bucket with only current objects, and the other one with all. There is also possibility of using `--start-after` if you would name your objects in alphabetical order based on timestamps. However, the two solutions mentioned above seem most prevalent.